# Simple regex. Get the number from [~21~]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this: [~21~]. How can I use regex to only return 21? The number can be any value (numbers), at any length. I am using Javascript with this regex, so if you could include that in your exsample, that would be great.

Thomas

Comment: Could you include slightly more detail about the string? For instance, will it always be an integer? Will it always be 2 digits? Will it ever be negative? Will it always be surrounded by ~ and [] ?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. Remove any other characters than digits
2. Parse the resulting number to a real number instead of a string

Like:

```
var number = parseInt(str.replace(/[\D]/g, ""), 10);
```

Where:

- `parseInt(..., 10)` parses any string to a number in base 10
- `str.replace(..., "")` will remove characters (replace them with nothing)
- `[\D]` means: anything except digits

For example,

```
parseInt("[~21~]".replace(/[\D]/g, ""), 10) === 21;
```

Note that it will concatenate numbers in e.g. `[~21~22~]`; that will become `2122`.

Comment: This will have unexpected behavior if you try to parse anything other than positive integers

Comment: @Robert Martin: You're correct. It becomes tricky if the string contains a `-` before the number but also somewhere else. I'm not sure what the exact format is of the input string.

Comment: yeah a negative number would have problems, as would a decimal (e.g. 0.2321 would be a lot bigger than you expected)

Comment: Note: `[^\d]` can be shortened to `\D`.

Comment: @pimvdb Did you mean `\D` instead of `\S`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex that will work in your case is:

```
[0-9]+
```

This will match a sequence of strings consisting of the characters: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't worried about error-handling:

```
 var getTheNumber = function(a) { return a.substring(0, a.length-2).substring(2); }
```

Comment: Not valid. To quote the question: "The number can be any value (numbers), at any length." And he asked about a regex.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.'   Now they have two problems."  A regexp wouldn't solve any problem the OP actually has.

Comment: I don't see why a regex wouldn't solve it. I use Perl and regexes all the time. They solve most problems fast and with minimal code.

Comment: I mean, the regex wouldn't solve any problem that just snipping off the first and last two characters wouldn't.  The OP isn't *actually* looking for a pattern, he just wants to snip off some characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
-*\d+(\.\d+)*
```

Contemplates negative and/or decimal numbers. This will extract any number of 1 or more digits no matter the string.